# Scheduling identical SSIS packages to run in parallel

Tags: ssis, package

We've got an architecture where we intend to use SSIS as a data-loading engine for incoming batches. The intent is to reduce the need for manual intervention & configuration and automate the  function as much as possible so we're looking at setting up our "batch monitoring" package to run as scheduled SQL Server Agent jobs.

Is it possible to schedule several SQL Server Agent jobs using the same package, possibly looking at different folders or working on different data chunks (grouped by batch ids?

We might also have 3 or 4 “jobs” all running the same package and all monitoring the same folder for incoming files, but at slightly different intervals to avoid file contention issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any reason you couldn't do this. You could launch the packages each with a different configuration (or configurations) pointing to different working directories, input folders, etc.